# Cutting an AV file (MP4)

Tags: video-editing, avconv

I have tried using openshot, pitivi, kdenlive, videolan to cut an audio/video file but they all seem to freeze. So I am now trying to use the following command:

```
avconv -i input.MP4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 01:25:00 -t 01:26:00 output.MP4
```

This creates a file on my computer but when I open it in vlc, I can only hear sound and the length is 37.04 minutes. It was supposed to be 1 minute long.

Also, just tried this:

```
ffmpeg -ss 01:24:30 -t 01:25:00 -i orginalfile -vcodec copy -acodec copy newfile
```

This doesn't cut the av file at all, it ends up being full length but only the audio is available, no video.

What am I doing wrong?

I have also tried:

```
avconv -i input.MP4 -ss 01:25:00 -t 01:26:00 -c:a copy -c:v copy output.MP4
```

and it gives me the same result as above.

---

Full output from both commands can be see here:

```
oshiro@home-desktop:~/Desktop$ avconv -i SDV_1195.MP4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 01:24:00 -t 01:25:30 2.MP4
avconv version 0.8.13-4:0.8.13-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Jul 15 2014 12:56:47 with gcc 4.6.3
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x1e8c7a0] max_analyze_duration reached
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'SDV_1195.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : avc1
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: avc1isom
    creation_time   : 1947-02-10 00:03:08
  Duration: 02:01:04.29, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2137 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p, 720x576, 2000 kb/s, PAR 64:45 DAR 16:9, 50 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1947-02-10 00:03:08
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 127 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1947-02-10 00:03:08
Output #0, mp4, to '2.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : avc1
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: avc1isom
    creation_time   : 1947-02-10 00:03:08
    encoder         : Lavf53.21.1
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: ![0][0][0] / 0x0021, yuv420p, 720x576 [PAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 2000 kb/s, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1947-02-10 00:03:08
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, 127 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1947-02-10 00:03:08
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
frame=    0 fps=  0 q=-1.0 Lsize=   35570kB time=2224.30 bitrate= 131.0kbits/s    /s    
video:0kB audio:34755kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 2.345804%
oshiro@home-desktop:~/Desktop$ avconv -i SDV_1195.MP4 -ss 01:24:00 -t 01:25:30 -c:a copy -c:v copy output-clip.mp4
avconv version 0.8.13-4:0.8.13-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Jul 15 2014 12:56:47 with gcc 4.6.3
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0xd307a0] max_analyze_duration reached
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'SDV_1195.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : avc1
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: avc1isom
    creation_time   : 1947-02-10 00:03:08
  Duration: 02:01:04.29, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2137 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p, 720x576, 2000 kb/s, PAR 64:45 DAR 16:9, 50 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1947-02-10 00:03:08
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 127 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1947-02-10 00:03:08
Output #0, mp4, to 'output-clip.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : avc1
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: avc1isom
    creation_time   : 1947-02-10 00:03:08
    encoder         : Lavf53.21.1
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: ![0][0][0] / 0x0021, yuv420p, 720x576 [PAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 2000 kb/s, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1947-02-10 00:03:08
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, 127 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1947-02-10 00:03:08
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
frame=    0 fps=  0 q=-1.0 Lsize=   35570kB time=2224.30 bitrate= 131.0kbits/s    /s    
video:0kB audio:34755kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 2.345804%
oshiro@home-desktop:~/Desktop$
```

Comment: Seems you can use `ffmpeg`. Check this answer. http://askubuntu.com/a/318132

Comment: @Ramesh, I just tried that, and it just seems to strip the video out and doesn't extract the clip I want.

Comment: oh, let's wait for some other answer then. Unfortunately, I could not test it in the machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've cut videos both on Linux and Windows using [Avidemux](http://avidemux.org). It has an easy to use GUI.

- load the video
- select start and end points
- select output format (use **Copy** to avoid video recoding)
- save your cut file

Install it in Ubuntu with:

```
sudo apt-get install avidemux
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The `-t` takes a *duration*, not *end-time*.

So change to `-t 60` or `-t 0:01:00`

From [libav doc](https://libav.org/avconv.html#Main-options):

```
‘-t duration (output)’
    Stop writing the output after its duration reaches duration.
    duration may be a number in seconds, or in hh:mm:ss[.xxx] form.
```